# React-Router - Link vs Redirect vs History

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

There seems to be some confusion with what to use over the other:

- `<Link to='/some/path'>`
- `<Redirect to='/some/path'/>`
- `history.push('/some/path')`

I have been using React/Router for a little while now, and different posts/answers say different things regarding when to use these, and sometimes they don't line up with what someone else said. So I think I need some clarification on this.

#### From what I understand about `Link` and this [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) it:

> Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application.

#### From what I understand about `Redirect` and this [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) it:

> Will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

It seems like all the posts I have read almost everyone uses `Redirect` to navigate around there application, and no one ever recommends using `Link` like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757676/in-react-is-it-always-better-to-render-a-redirect-than-use-this-props-history-pu?rq=1).

Now `history` can do the same thing as `Link` and `Redirect` except I have a history stack trace.

**Question 1:** When would I want to use `Link` vs `Redirect`, what's the use case over the other?

**Question 2:** Since `history` can route a user to another location in-app with the added bonus of the history stack, should I always just use the history object when routing?

**Question 3:** If I want to route *outside* of the app, what's the best method to do so? Anchor tag, Window.location.href, Redirect, Link, none of the above?

Comment: 1. `Link` makes you navigate around your app when clicking on them. When `Redirect` is rendered, it will push an entry on the `history` stack automatically. 2. E.g. clicking a `Link` also pushes an entry to the `history` stack, so if you can use `Link` for your purposes, it is usually easier than manipulating the `history` yourself. 3. A regular `<a>` tag works great.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First off, I would really recommend reading through this site:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

React Router's `BrowserRouter` maintains the history stack for you, which means that you rarely need to modify it manually.

But to answer your questions:
**Answer 1:** You'll want to use `Link` or `NavLink` in almost all use cases. `Redirect` comes in handy in specific situations though, an example is when a 404 page is rendered when the user tries to access an undefined route. The `Redirect` will redirect the user from the 404 route to a new route of your choosing, and then replace the last entry in the history stack with the redirected route.

This means that the user will not be able to hit their browser's back button, and return to the 404 route.

`Link` `NavLink` and `Redirect` all use the router's history api under the hood, using these components instead of history manually means that you are safe to any changes to the history api in the future. Using these components future-proofs your code.

**Answer 2:** `BrowserRouter` Maintains the history stack for you, generally my opinion is that you want to stay away from manually updating it where you can.

**Answer 3:** Here are a few examples for external react links:

```
<Route path='/external' component={() => window.location = 'https://external.com/path'}/>
```

---

```
<a href='https://external.com/path' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Regular Anchor tags work great</a>
```

`target='_blank'` will open the link in a new tab, but please make sure to include `rel='noopener noreferrer'` to prevent against [vulnerabilities](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/)

Comment: Note about `target='_blank'`: recommend adding [`rel='noopener noreferrer'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable) to your `<a>` tag

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher thank you! This is new to me - I've updated the answer.